# how to disable pep8 in pycharm for a code block

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8, pep

I want to disable pep8 for a block of code for example, a an array which has long text, I do not want it to complain about line too long. How can I disable the pep8 inspection only for that array?

Comment: Does the approach from here work: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor ? I.E. add `# noinspection PyPep8` before the line